# Set div scrollbar to specific position

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar

I am using this javascript ([Super Table](http://www.matts411.com/post/super_tables)) to transform my table in a div to freeze the top header and left column. The scrollable area has columns with textboxes that corrospond to a specific month and year. I would like to have the horizontal scroll position to match the current month and year. I create the table programmatically and add it to a placeholder in an asp.net code behind.

Is it possible to add a class to a table cell and then use javascript or jquery to move the horizontal scroll bar to the table cell with the current month class? If so, how? I am not that great with javascript beyond the basic validation stuff. Any other ideas would be appriciated, too.

Thank you.

Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

This plugin might help you out: http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html

---

Using purely HTML you can give it an id instead a class and then at the end of the url you would add "#id_here" and the page should navigate to the cell.  However, I have never tried that in a scrolling div, so I can't be for sure.

Example code:

```
<td id="current_date"></td>
```

Then the link would be:

```
Page.aspx#current-date
```

Comment: This didn't work. It seemed to mess up the way the table rendered, and it also moved the vertical scrollbar and not the horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: Your update worked perfectly. Thank you! For anyone else that needs to use it, the trick is to use the tables onfinish event to assign a function that uses the sData class to specify where to scroll to.